# django checkbox unchecked despite initial=True

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form containing a boolean field, "reduction." The field has an initial value of True (i.e. I want the corresponding checkbox to render as checked). My problem is that this doesn't happen. When the form first renders, the checkbox is unchecked.

Searching for this topic yields a ton of issues related to the value of the checkbox on submit, and how it doesn't send anything if unchecked, etc. But I can't figure out why Django isn't initially checking this box. I've verified that the value of the field in the form is indeed true when the form is passed to the template from the view. Any ideas?

The Form:

```
class RunParamsForm(Form):
    fluid_present = BooleanField(widget=HiddenInput, required=False)
    solid_init_present = BooleanField(widget=HiddenInput, required=False)
    solid_sim_present = BooleanField(widget=HiddenInput, required=False)
    solid_present = BooleanField(widget=HiddenInput, required=False)
    load_map_present = BooleanField(widget=HiddenInput, required=False)
    scallop_map_present = BooleanField(widget=HiddenInput, required=False)
    fluid_endtim_units = CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'units', 'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    solid_init_drterm_units = CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'units', 'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    solid_sim_endtim_units = CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'units', 'readonly': 'readonly'}))
    steps = CharField(widget=HiddenInput)
    reduction = BooleanField(initial=True, required=False)
```

The relevant html:

```
<!-- REDUCTION BLOCK -->
<div class="block1">
    <div class="queueRunHeading">
        Other
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <label for="{{ form.reduction.id_for_label }}">
            1-Dimensional Reduction
        </label>
        {{ form.reduction }}
        <span class="errorlist">
            {{ form.reduction.errors.as_text }}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your view.

Comment: Ah, nuts. In the process of getting the info to post my view I got to thinking about the way I'm instantiating the form. I was passing in a dictionary to initialize some of the fields. I was not messing touching this "reduction" field but Django must be interpreting the missing info as a False.